# $|\mu|(A)=0 \Leftrightarrow \mu(B)=0$ for $B \subseteq A$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I want to solve the following exercise:

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure, then

$|\mu|(A)=0 \Leftrightarrow \mu(B)=0$ for every measurable $B \subseteq A$.

Lets start with $\Rightarrow$:
Assume that $|\mu|(A)=0$, by definition
$|\mu|(A)=\sup\{\sum_{i=1}^n |\mu(B_i)|:B_i \text{ are disjoint and } B_i \subseteq A\}$

So, let $B_1,...,B_n$ be disjoint subsets of $A$ and $0=\sum_{i=1}^n|\mu(B_i)|$, since we only sum positive numbers, it follows that

$0=\mu(B_i)$ for all $i=1,...,n$

Since $n$ was arbitrary, it holds for $n=1$, thus $\mu(B)=0$ for every $B \subseteq A$.

Now the other direction $\Leftarrow$:
Since $\mu(B)=0$, for every $B \subseteq A$,
$\{\sum_{i=1}^n |\mu(B_i)|:B_i \text{ are disjoint and } B_i \subseteq A\}=\{0\}$. Thus the supremum of this set is equal to $0$.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.